# My html5 game is not working in BB10 simulator

Tags: html, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I have created one html5 game.

As per bb10 webworks guidelines I have made config.xml file.
my game is working fine in ripple emulator .But when i tested it in BB10 Dev Alpha Simulator only black screen appears..
what is issue??
I have uploaded my code [here.](https://www.box.com/s/4ds7bk7tr7n3hlz4m4wu)

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"
    version="1.0.0.5" id="mani" xml:lang="en">
     <author href="http://www.example.com/"
      rim:copyright="Copyright 1998-2012 My Corp">My Corp</author>
      <name>mani</name>
<icon src="logo.png"/>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <feature id="blackberry.identity" required="true" version="1.0.0.0"/>
    </widget>
```

And I added script tag in index.html file.
Rest thing is untouched.

index.html

```
      <script src="local:///chrome/webworks.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Please post the config.xml here.

Comment: Don't upload your whole project like this.......

Comment: I have posted the config.xml file.

Comment: Have you tried to get more info with the chrome inspector?

Comment: no..How chrome inspector will be useful for that? My game is working perfectly in ripple but not in bb10 simulator.

Comment: yeah I tried..But my file is not shown in Chrome Inspection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a black screen, then I expect there is a runtime error that has prevented your game from starting and/or

Here are instructions on how to use remote-web inspector. I recommend connecting, opening the console panel and reloading your app.  It should tell you right away if there is an error:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/web_inspector_overview_1553586_11.html

Do you have any remote content being used in your app?  If so, I suspect the application does not have permission to access that content as I don't see any <access> elements in your config.xml.  Make sure you properly whitelist all remote URLs: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/access_element_834677_11.html